# Android:Simple USSD Dialer Application

Tags: android

I have created a simple dialer to quickly help me dial mobile provider services like checking air balance, getting internet settings from the provider

```
//example
phoneNum[1] = "*144#";
```

When i click a button for checking balance  it says Dialing

```
 Dialing *144
```

*144 and notice the hash isn't there but it should operate as ussd code if the hash was available and return the  balance instead of calling. How do i add the hash to the array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should escape the # symbol with %23

`//example
phoneNum[1] = "*144";`

```
String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.DIAL",
              Uri.parse("tel:"+ phoneNum[1]+ encodedHash)));
```

As for the catching the response, you should experiment with

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", 
                   Uri.parse("tel:"+ phoneNum[1]+ encodedHash)), 1);
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
    view.setText("USSD: " + requestCode + " " + resultCode + " " + data);
}
```

and see what will that return you.

Comment: Thanks for this, what if i want to dial it directly without going to the dial window?

Comment: How do you mean? When you put the `startActivityForResult(..)` in `onClick` of your button it will dial it automatically.

Comment: You should read a little about [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)) and [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)) first.

Comment: @ Karadza3a , thanks a lot, i could now dial direct and get the result, i am now trying in the case of *450*1#. Do i need to do a uri encode for the second asterisk and escape with %23? I have tried but it does not take that

Comment: No, you only need to escape hash (#), you can put as many asterisks you want (ie. "*123*5*2*4") just substitute "#" with `String encodedHash`