# launch *#*#4636#*#* from my app

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm writing an app, and I need to dial or call (I'm not sure) *#*#4636#*#*. This is the code I use:

```
       selred.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {


              Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                Uri.parse("tel:*#*#4636#*#*")); //
              startActivity(i);


         }
    });
```

But it's only dialing "*". Can I do it or is it impossible?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399033/androidsimple-ussd-dialer-application you need to encode the hash (`#`)

Comment: I think its an preserved numbers, you cant call it.  But not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is going to be impossible.

The number you're "dialling" is a special sequence that the phone intercepts to perform some sort of service action, in this case revealing internal information about the phone. But these sequences aren't actually dialled: the phone initiates the request as soon as you get to the last character, without your needing to press the call button.

You'd be better off working out what this sequence does, and seeing if there's a way of doing the same thing using the API.

Comment: My intention was to restrict traffic to 2g only but I have been looking long and apart from this number (*#*#4636#*#*) the only thing I got is something about a domestic android APIs that seemed very difficult to reach implement. any idea?